# When access to my address http://localhost.com/magento2 i got an error

Tags: magento2, php, ubuntu, php-7.4

At final phase to install Magento 2, When i went to access my address  http://localhost.com/magento2 i got an error cause of index.php file, my address does not read the file as php file

so i got the following error

```
run($app); * -------------------------------------------- * * Copyright Â© Magento, Inc. All rights reserved. * See COPYING.txt for license details. */ try { require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php'; } catch (/Exception $e) { echo <<
Autoload error

{$e->getMessage()}
HTML; exit(1); } $bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER); /** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app */ $app = $bootstrap->createApplication(\Magento\Framework\App\Http::class); $bootstrap->run($app);
```

and the original file code is

```
<?php

/*
 * Application entry point
 *
 * Example - run a particular store or website:
 * --------------------------------------------
 * require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
 * $params = $_SERVER;
 * $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'website2';
 * $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website';
 * $bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
 * \/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app *\/
 * $app = $bootstrap-createApplication(\Magento\Framework\App\Http::class);
 * $bootstrap->run($app);
 * --------------------------------------------
 *
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

try {
    require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
} catch (/Exception $e) {
    echo <<<HTML
<meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
<div style="font:12px/1.35em arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">
    <div style="margin:0 0 25px 0; border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;">
        <h3 style="margin:0;font-size:1.7em;font-weight:normal;text-transform:none;text-align:left;color:#2f2f2f;">
        Autoload error</h3>
    </div>
    <p>{$e->getMessage()}</p>
</div>
HTML;
    exit(1);
}

$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app */
$app = $bootstrap->createApplication(\Magento\Framework\App\Http::class);
$bootstrap->run($app);
```

after my researching i got that my address does not read/run the php file as is, it is read/run it as html file, so my question is: how can i let the server run the php file as is ?

additional info : my file is in /var/www/html/magento2/index.php

php version is php 7.4.3

Comment: did u tried downgrading ur php version

Comment: No i did not, i am beginner in this field and i do not know what is the right version

Comment: did the updated ans works for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error solved, what i do is removing the Apache2 Virtual Host and reinstalling it ,then there's syntax error here :

```
try {
    require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
} catch (/Exception $e) {  <-------------- here that '/' slash .
    echo <<<HTML
<meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
<div style="font:12px/1.35em arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">
    <div style="margin:0 0 25px 0; border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;">
        <h3 style="margin:0;font-size:1.7em;font-weight:normal;text-transform:none;text-align:left;color:#2f2f2f;">
        Autoload error</h3>
    </div>
    <p>{$e->getMessage()}</p>
</div>
HTML;
    exit(1);
}
```

by  removing it, the error disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

PHP
~7.4.0
Magento 2.x.x can be installed with 7.3, but it is not tested or recommended. It is intended for upgrading from Magento 2.3.x to Magento 2.4.0.

There is a bug in PHP 7.4.2 which causes some messages to not render properly. Magento recommends using other versions of 7.4.

Source:- https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html you can visit the link to learn more about magento technology requirement

UPDATE:-
follow this terminal command to install php other version

```
sudo apt-get install -y php7.0 libapache2-mod-php7.0 php7.0 php7.0-common php7.0-gd php7.0-mysql php7.0-mcrypt php7.0-curl php7.0-intl php7.0-xsl php7.0-mbstring php7.0-zip php7.0-bcmath php7.0-iconv php7.0-soap
```

remember to change php version 7.0 with your required version 7.3 or 7.2 and then just disable php 7.4 and enable php 7.3 or 7.2 using below commands

```
sudo a2dismod php7.4 
 sudo a2enmod php7.2
 sudo service apache2 restart
```

**UPDATE:-**
SET PERMISSION LIKE THIS THEN

```
sudo chown www-data:www-data -R /var/www/html/magento2

sudo chmod 777 -R /var/www/html/magento2
```

please note magento2 will be your root directory so replace it with yours

Comment: I am follow your instructions, and i don't know if the server read the file properly or not, but now shows a blank page, no errors appear, i don't know where is the problem.

Comment: where exactly ur getting the blank page? while accessing admin panel?

Comment: where access same address localhost.com/magento2 to get Magento Setup Wizard as the following:[link](https://cdn2.mageplaza.com/media/general2/ySUWqGm.png)

Comment: please confirm that its not the permission issue if yes then run this command sudo chmod -R 777 var/www/html/magento2 change the location according to your requirement

Comment: I don't know how to check if the issue is permission issue, anyway I used this command but nothing changed

Comment: ok which php version u are using?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111871/discussion-between-chikku-and-s-j).

Comment: check the updated ans

Comment: ok that's better

Comment: so its working?

Comment: no i mean better to continue this dicussion in chat